# Updating a Docker container with new code

Tags: python, docker

I've looked at some other answers but none seem to be quite what I'm looking for.

I've got a python bot I've written that I turned in to a docker container that's launched via

`docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped -v /home/dockeradmin/pythonApp/:/pythonApp--name python-bot-app  python-bot`

My question though is that how to update my docker container when I change the code for my python project. Right now I usually will just rebuild the image, stop/prune the container, and then start it again, however this seems to be extremely wasteful.

Is there a simple or "right" way to do this?

Comment: With a registry: The only less wasteful thing I can think of is when you let docker pull the latest version of your image before deleting the old one it will use its cache efficiently for the pulling process.
Without a registry: The build cache of the image also makes the process more efficient without deleting the image before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've got a python bot I've written that I turned in to a docker container that's launched via

```
docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped \
  -v /home/dockeradmin/pythonApp/:/pythonApp \
  --name python-bot-app  python-bot
```

This is a very common way to run containers in a development environment like your laptop. The name on the container lets you easily find your container and manage it. The volume mount includes the current code in your container on top of whatever was built in the image at that same location. If you restart the container, the volume mount will restart the app with that new code in the container, which should mean testing a change in python only involves a:

```
docker container restart python-bot
```

> My question though is that how to update my docker container when I change the code for my python project.

When you get into deploying the application in production, the above is less than ideal. You need something that is easily redeployed, the ability to backout changes quickly if there's an error, and most importantly you need to avoid the risk of state drift. The standard workflow into production involves:

1. Checkin code changes to version control
2. Have a build server detect those changes and create a new image with a unique tag
3. Push that image to a registry server
4. Deploy that image in a dev, CI, stage, and prod environment according to your organization policies

The important parts are that you do not upgrade containers in place, all of the code is inside the image rather than being mounted with a volume (you still have volumes for data), and you also don't give containers anything unique that would prevent scaling like a container name.

> Right now I usually will just rebuild the image, stop/prune the container, and then start it again, however this seems to be extremely wasteful.

On a single node implementation, you can start with `docker-compose` to replace the container, and it will handle the stop and restart steps for you. When you get into multi-node environments, you'll want Swarm Mode or Kubernetes to handle rolling updates of your application, providing HA and avoiding any outage during the update of your app.

When working with containers, you minimize waste by efficiently layering your image, reusing the build cache, and shipping images with a registry server. Docker's filesystem layers build on top of each other to create an image, and if you only change a few files in the last layer, only those changes are sent when the updated image is deployed. Any changes to an application will involve restarting that application at a minimum, and a container is only a bit of additional kernel API calls to run that application with settings to create its own namespace and restrictions. The only addition you have with recreating a container vs restarting it is a bit of added housekeeping to remove old images and possibly some stopped containers. But the advantage you gain in knowing that your entire environment is reproducible without any state drift is worth the added effort.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because I think it's got a ton of great information. In my case it ended up that I was just being an idiot, the reason mounting the directory with -v wasn't working is just because in my DockerFile I wasn't copying things in to that new directory.

Answer (score 3):

Rebuilding your image when your code changes is the canonical approach, and is not wasteful at all if done right.

Your `pythonApp` code should be `COPY`'d into your image as the final step (rule of thumb: most frequently changed step in dockerfile should go last). This means rebuilding will be very fast as all other steps will be cached. If you only have a few kB of source code changes it will only result in a single new layer of a few kB. Stopping and starting containers is also very light weight.

There is nothing to worry about in following this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "simple" but probably not "right" way to do that - I can classify that as "workaround".

Firstly start your working container, I will use ubuntu as example but you can of course adjust that to your needs:

```
docker run -dit --name work-container -v /path-to-code:/code ubuntu bash -c "while true; do sleep 10; done"
```

So that command will start ubuntu for you in background with endless loop. In `-v` section you should mount your code which you change. So now open new console and type:

```
docker exec -it work-container bash
```

So that command start new shell inside that background container. So in that shell you can do whatever you want inside container e.g. `cd /code && ./do-something-with-your-python`. As your code is mounted under /code in container you will see changes in real time and you can run some program a then hit ctrl+c and restart it after code changes.